# Applications in the Menu Bar & The Ability to choose which are Active upon startup?

Tags: applications, menu-bar

Are the applications located towards the right side of the menu bar next to system icons automatically active upon boot up of an apple mac. What decides which apps sit there & is there a way to choose which apps are active and sit in the menu bar by default at startup ?

Indeed if one is using a 13" Macbook Pro (like myself) or even an 11" Macbook Air, what happens when the number of apps gets to the extent where they begin to close the gap towards what I believe is usually **help** located towards the left of the menu bar. If your using a 27" display I guess this scenario doesnt occur.

Is there a way to minimise those apps in the menu bar whilst keeping them active if required ?

Thankyou

Comment: There is an article written today 5th Dec. 2012 "Dock Too Crowded? Too Many Utilities In The Mac’s Menubar? Try A Custom Menu" by J Miller for Mac360.com describing another App to the one mentioned below which should also be v. useful for this: http://mac360.com/2012/12/dock-too-crowded-too-many-utilities-in-the-mac-menubar-try-a-custom-previe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com) to hide status menu items and menu extras.

Many applications have options to disable opening them at login or to hide the status menu items. You can also remove login items from System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: Oh Lauri, you answered so quickly :), i'll chackout Bartender. Thx very much

Comment: Hopefully everyone now with smaller screens will benefit from this the advice given above without any loss in functionality